# Como estratificar (agrupar) observações dentro de uma variável específica por mais de uma categoria no R?

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com uma tabela das agências bancárias por endereço do Brasil que possui 20.580 observações e 15 variáveis. Meu objetivo é criar uma nova variável com os grupos das regiões a partir das observações da variável "uf", mas como vocês podem perceber abaixo não há variáveis com os códigos numéricos dos municípios ou dos estados. Por isso, fiz duas tentativas diferentes para tentar formar os grupos, no entanto não obtive êxito.

A tabela apresenta as seguintes variáveis (eu alterei os nomes originais):

```
 [1] "cnpj"         "seq_cnpj"     "dv_cnpj"      "instituicao"  "segmento"     "cod_com_area"
 [7] "nome_agencia" "endereco"     "complemento"  "bairro"       "cep"          "municipio"   
[13] "uf"           "ddd"          "fone"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Na primeira tentativa**, eu tentei via comando "rename", mas o output informou que a leitura é apenas para objetos numéricos, ver abaixo:

O nome do arquivo é "agencias".

## 1 Tentativa: criar grupos de região com observações categóricas dentro da variável "uf"

```
agencias$regiao <- row.names(agencias$uf)<-c("norte" = "RO" | "AC" | "AM" | "RR" | "PA" | "AP" | "TO",
                                             "nordeste" = "MA" | "PI" | "CE" | "RN" | "PB" | "PE" | "AL" 
                                             | "SE" | "BA",
                                             "sudeste" = "MG" | "ES" | "RJ" | "SP",
                                             "sul" = "PR" | "SC" | "RS",
                                             "centro_oeste" = "MS" | "MT" | "GO" | "DF")
```

> Error in "RO" | "AC" :     operações são possíveis somente para tipos
>   numéricos, lógicos ou complexos

**Na segunda tentativa**, eu criei uma variável numérica para os estados a partir da transformação da variável "uf":

```
agencias$uf <- as.factor(agencias$uf)
agencias$num_uf <- as.numeric(agencias$uf)
```

Como não consegui definir no comando "transformação" a numeração de cada Estado de acordo com os códigos do IBGE, a numeração saiu na ordem do R. Dessa forma, eu usei os número atribuídos pelo R para formar os grupos regionais. O comando rodou perfeitamente, mas ao verificar a coluna "região" recém criada, no lugar dos nomes das regiões, aparece a sigla "NA" de significado "Not Available", ou seja, "Não Disponível".

## 2 Tentativa: criar grupos de região com observações numéricas dentro da variável "num_uf"

```
attach(agencias)

agencias$regiao[num_uf==21 & num_uf==1 & num_uf==3 & num_uf==22 & num_uf==14 & num_uf==4 & num_uf==27] <- "norte"

agencias$regiao[num_uf==10 & num_uf==17 & num_uf==6 & num_uf==20 & num_uf==15 & num_uf==16 & num_uf==2 & num_uf==25 & num_uf==5] <- "nordeste"

agencias$regiao[num_uf==11 & num_uf==8 & num_uf==19 & num_uf==26] <- "sudeste"

agencias$regiao[num_uf==18 & num_uf==24 & num_uf==23] <- "sul"

agencias$regiao[num_uf==12 & num_uf==13 & num_uf==9 & num_uf==7] <- "centro_oeste"

detach(agencias)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com este ponto? Existe alguma forma de estratificar essa variável categórica?

OBS: eu baixei a tabela do site do Banco Central do Brasil no link "agências", disponível em

```
https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/agenciasconsorcio
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

obrigado pela sua contribuição.

Eu consegui resolver a questão de outra forma. Primeiro eu transformei a variável em numérica e depois codifiquei as variáveis através do comando "recode". Mas a sua sugestão é mais direta e avançada, com certeza irei usar. Obrigado!

## Transformando e criando variável de fator (factor) para numérica (numeric)

```
agencias$num_uf <- as.numeric(agencias$uf)
```

## Visualizar a numeração das ufs

```
table(agencias$uf)
table(agencias$num_uf)
```

## Criando categorias regionais a partir das observações numéricas (numeric) dentro de uma variável

```
agencias$regiao <- recode(agencias$num_uf, 
                          `21` = "norte", `1` = "norte", `3` = "norte", `22` = "norte",
                          `14` = "norte", `4` = "norte", `27` = "norte",
                          `10` = "nordeste", `17` = "nordeste", `6` = "nordeste",
                          `20` = "nordeste", `15` = "nordeste", `16` = "nordeste",
                           `2` = "nordeste", `25` = "nordeste", `5` = "nordeste",
                          `11` = "sudeste", `8` = "sudeste", `19` = "sudeste", `26` = 
                           "sudeste",
                          `18` = "sul", `24` = "sul", `23` = "sul",
                          `12` = "centro_oeste", `13` = "centro_oeste", `9` = 
                           "centro_oeste",
                          `7` = "centro_oeste")
```